# Строка в шенадцатиричный массив байт

Tags: java, hex

Имеется строка.
Требуется записать её в четырёхбайтовом формате
Например, строка "1" будет выглядеть следующим образом:
00 00 00 01
Потому что при переводе 1 в шестнадцатиричный формат получаем 1

А строка "1000" будет выглядеть следующим образом:
00 00 03 E8
Потому что 1000 в десятичной системе счисления - это 3E8 в шестнадцатиричной

Никак не пойму, как это реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо сначала привести вашу строку к числу, а затем достаточно вызвать метод `Integer.toHexString`

```
String strValue = "1000";
int value = Integer.parseInt(strValue);

System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(value));
```